# How to save handwritten note into the PDF?

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat

I created some handwritten note in a PDF file following [this instruction](https://answers.acrobatusers.com/How-to-I-add-handwritten-notes-and-drawings-to-an-adobe-file-q130428.aspx). But when someone else open the file in other PDF clients, they do not see the note.  How do I save the note as "true" visible part of the PDF?

Comment: What other PDF clients are people opening your file in? It's possible that they're opening it in something that can't read annotations.

Comment: One of PDF clients is called Skim.  I don't want the handwritten note/text be annotations or a different type/layer of content. How do I make them on the same level/layer as the original content?

Comment: To get the note on the imaging level of the PDF, you would flatten the annotations.

Comment: 'Flatten' is a generic/abstract English verb in this context and is NOT helpful at all. The entire question is about how to concretely do the 'flattening'.